# How to format servlet response to produce media types acceptable by "accept" parameter in HTML?

Tags: java, html, servlets, types, response

I want to understand how the response to browsers works. As an example, jersey says it responds a request with most acceptable media type defined by annotation @Produces:

```
 @GET
 @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
 public String doGetAsXmlOrJson() {
   ...
 }
```

In the case above, the most acceptable type is "application/xml". Well... For this media type, I would do in Servlet:

```
response.setContentType("application/xml");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<root><x>1</x></root>");
```

The point is: I need to format the response according to the media type, as I done above in last line.

I want to know how to format, using HttpServletResponse, the second acceptable type, supposing browser doesn't support "application/xml". In this situation, "application/json" should be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know what media type the client supports unless it tells you. This is usually done with the [`Accept` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media
>   types which are acceptable for the response.

So if the client sends

```
Accept: application/xml
```

You should try to produce an `application/xml` formatted response.

```
String mediaType = request.getHeader("Accept"); // can return null
```

If you can't produce such a response, you should respond with a [`406 Not Acceptable`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) status code with an appropriate body.

Comment: @LucasBatistussi Just edited. The `HttpServletRequest` has a `getHeader()` method which returns the header value or `null` if it doesn't exist.